# Should I check in this android folder in my react-native git repo?

Tags: android, react-native

I ran git status and saw the following files under android/app/ I am not sure if I need to check in these files into my git repo or not.

```
android/app/.gitignore
android/app/app/
android/app/gradle.properties
android/app/gradle/
android/app/gradlew
android/app/gradlew.bat
android/app/settings.gradle
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Android and iOS folders should be committed to git.

The reason for this is that if you need to write any native code/modify xcode projects/etc, not having this information in the repo will mean that you'll need to set it up manually whenever you pull the repo to a new location.  Also, this may make setting up CI such as Bitrise very difficult, as this usually relies on having a native project to build.